# Python weird NameError

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have a NameError that I cannot seem to be able to find the reason for. The error trace ends like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../new_main.py", line 61, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File ".../new_main.py", line 39, in main
    mp = build()
  File ".../common.py", line 54, in build
    m = r.build_from_config(map_config, character_config)
  File ".../config_reader.py", line 148, in build_from_config
    item["squares"]
  File ".../new_map.py", line 49, in build_map
    self.view = MapView(self)
  File ".../new_map.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.screen = reset_screen()
NameError: name 'reset_screen' is not defined
```

The class `MapView()` is in the file `new_map.py` and that file has this line in the imports:

```
from common import *
```

And the file `common.py` has the following function in it.

```
def reset_screen():
    # check if display has been initialized
    if not pygame.display.get_init():
        pygame.init()

    # set screen
    #flags = pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.DOUBLEBUF
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode( options.window_size )
    # fill with black
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    return screen
```

What am I missing?

---

E: here are my imports for each file.

**`new_main.py`:**

```
from common import *
from new_map import Map, MapView
import pygame, sys
```

**`common.py`:**

```
import pygame
import options
from config_reader import ConfigReader
from constants import *
from coordinates import Coordinates
```

**`config_reader.py`:**

```
from action import Action
from new_map import Map
from object_type import ObjectType
from squaretype import SquareType
from new_character import Character
from coordinates import Coordinates
import direction
```

**`new_map.py`:**

```
from square import Square
from common import *
from constants import *
from coordinates import Coordinates
from map_object import MapObject
from object_type import ObjectType
from new_character import Character
from turn import TurnController
import pygame, os
```

Comment: Does `from common import reset_screen` work? Do you need an `__init__.py`?

Comment: Check for circular imports.

Comment: i tried your construct, with a main.py including new_map.py which includes common.py. my new_map function called common function and was called in main. everything worked, so the error must be in your files the way you import maybe... can you please post more of your files so we can see the imports

Comment: @PaulRooney `from common import reset_screen` gives an ImportError, so there is something wrong with the imports. I'm using pygame, at least to my knowledge there is no conflicting `common` module? I'm in the middle of major restructuring, the full project is here: https://github.com/roopepal/discoknights/tree/restructuring

Comment: Try temporarily renaming your common module to see if it stops the problem.

Comment: I am using `reset_screen()` once earlier in the main function and it has no problems, so at least there the import is successful with the current name.

Comment: Yep, you have an import loop. Those are nasty.

Comment: Please see my imports above, if you can spot the loop before I do.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, I solved it by moving `build()` to `config_reader.py` and removing the import from `common.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your trace i can also just figure that in your `common.py` your are including `new_map.py` which causes the import in new_map to fail. If i do that to my test files, i get the same error:

my main - which imports both but still won't cause circular reference:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from common import *  # <-- this is ok
    from new_map import * # <-- this is no problem 
    do_something()
    test()
```

my commons:

```
from new_map import *    # <--- this will cause the problem

def reset_screen():
    return 1

def do_something():
    return test()
```

my new_map:

```
from common import *    # <--- this will fail then

def test():
    return reset_screen()
```

So you will have to split you common.py to the parts using new_map and the other that don't, and in new_map then import the version that holds the functions without new_map inclusion.

common_map.py

```
from new_map import *

def do_something()
    return test()
```

common_nomap.py

```
def reset_screen()
    return 1
```

new_map.py:

```
from common_nomap import *

def test()
    return reset_screen()
```

main.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from common_map import *  # <-- this is ok
    from new_map import *     # <-- this is no problem 
    do_something()
    test()
```

Comment: It was a circular import, but `new_map.py` was never included in `common.py`. But I solved it by moving the build function to the `config_reader.py` file. Was my first import loop, thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible scenarios I can think of:

1. Circular deps: it looks like **common.py** activates the function in **new_map.py** (via **config_reader.py**), which might cause **new_map.py** not to import **common.py**
2. Is there a **common** package you might be importing instead of **common.py**?